# Eager loading with route model binding

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I have a controller function like this

```
public function show(NovelRequest $request, Novel $novel)
{
    // load the chapters
    $novel->chapters;

    // return the detail view of a novel
    return view('novels.show', compact('novel'));
}
```

I receive a novel object because i m using route model binding. However, I'd like to load more than the chapters. Since it would cause many request if i now do something like

```
$novel->chapters;
$novel->bookmarks;
...
```

I wondered if theres a way to load "multiple" relations when i already have the novel object. Usually i would to something like

```
Novel::with('chapters', 'bookmarks')-> ...
```

However, I already have the novel object so i would like to not look it up a second time.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There is “[Lazy Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading)“.
The syntax is `$novel->load('chapters', 'bookmarks');`

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what i needed

Answer (score 6):

We can **eager** load the needed relations by customizing the resolution logic (for route model binding) by defining a `resolveRouteBinding` method on the model.

```
// In the Novel model
public function resolveRouteBinding($value)
{
    return $this->with(['chapters', 'bookmarks'])->where($this->getRouteKeyName(), $value)->firstOrFail();
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#explicit-binding

Comment: that's also a good solution, however it would always load the chapters & bookmarks and not only in the context where I actually need them